# Java missing button text

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I set text for buttons,  but when I run the project  - text on the button is missing.
(Font is Tahoma 11 plain)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A little more info would _really_ be helpful. Just a general hint: the more effort you put into your question the more effort we'd put into our answers.

Comment: I have updated my question. I set a text only in desing mode...

Comment: i tried  to use (arial,tahoma,times new roman), still the same effect . I can`t see the text on button.

Comment: I have put four new buttons (u can see the result) , i don`t see the text on buttons) (I have updated my question)

Comment: Do you have any code which is updating buttons properties dynamically, like size?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Click your button in design mode, pause for a second and click again, if it's NetBeans you are using. Try changing your text that way, it will let you change it that way also. Hopefully that might work.  Regards

Comment: thx..!! I just tried to use clean project!!

Comment: The "convert" button displays perfectly, so it should not be a problem of Font. Check what the difference is between the buttons. Maybe there are some misconfigurations for other properties for the buttons.

Comment: I've got a similar problem in that buttons with the default Tahoma font display garbled.  However, it's only on certain machines.  Most display it fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ttry to clean the  project ( mouseover on project -> clean project)